# Panda.run_sql_query for where .. in .. structure?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, cx-oracle

I have a sql query with structure of where a in b kind. I am trying to run it through pandas with run_sql_query to get dataframe back. But no data structure seems to work with panda query. What should i have there to make it work?

sql:

```
Select * from Table where a in (:input)
```

Python:

```
conn = cx-oracle.connect(....)

df = pd.run_sql_query(sql,conn, params= {'input':('A','B')})
```

Error message:

```
cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Python value of type tuple not supported.
```

I tried numpy array and list but none seems to work. What data structure should be used here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myinput = ('a','b','c')
myinput = str(myinput)
#Now your query will end up like
# select * from tablename where value in ('a','b','c')
df = pd.run_sql_query(sql,conn, params= {'input':myinput})
```

Comment: Bro use triple quotes, like this:   {'input':"' 'A' , 'B' '"}

Comment: how can i do that? in this case, there is a tuple with 2 elements. what I had been doing right now was join to make string and if I do add 1 more quotation: it's like          " ' 'A' ,'B' ' " and doesnot yet work

Comment: Try to modify my code and then try. I see you are doing it manually, that's not a good practice. Typecast tuple to string and use it in query.